# Как настроить кластер в Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Хочу настроить кластер из 3-х машин (2 дата ноды, 1 мастер). На данный момент пытаюсь настроить минимум из 1 дата и мастер ноды. Порты пришлось поменять в силу специфики сети, но думаю проблема не в этом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Конфиг мастер ноды.**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  master:
    image: elasticsearch:8.1.1
    container_name: master
    environment:
      - node.name=master
      - cluster.name=elastic-cluster
      - network.host=0.0.0.0

      - discovery.seed_hosts=10.126.107.238:1029, 10.126.107.236:1029
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=10.126.107.238

      - "node.roles=master"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=false"

    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - master-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 1028:9200
      - 1029:9300

volumes:
  master-data:
    driver: local
```

**Конфиг дата-ноды**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  node01:
    image: elasticsearch:8.1.1
    container_name: node01
    environment:
      - node.name=node01
      - cluster.name=elastic-cluster
      - network.host=0.0.0.0

      - discovery.seed_hosts=10.126.107.238:1029, 10.126.107.236:1029
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=10.126.107.238

      - "node.roles=data"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=false"
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - master-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 1028:9200
      - 1029:9300

volumes:
  master-data:
    driver: local
```

Когда **дата-нода** пытается подключиться - выдаёт следующие логи

> node01  | {"@timestamp":"2022-08-07T08:15:38.096Z", "log.level":
> "WARN", "message":"[connectToRemoteMasterNode[10.126.107.238:1029]]
> completed handshake with
> [{master}{5_tf1e03S4CYx_v4j4tTyw}{4LhWtmyPTaGKY5x_4Sf10g}{192.168.16.2}{192.168.16.2:9300}{m}{xpack.installed=true}]
> but followup connection failed", "ecs.version":
> "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[node01][generic][T#2]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.discovery.HandshakingTransportAddressConnector","elasticsearch.node.name":"node01","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elastic-cluster","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException","error.message":"[master][192.168.16.2:9300]
> connect_exception","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException:
> [master][192.168.16.2:9300] connect_exception\n\tat
> org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$ChannelsConnectedListener.onFailure(TcpTransport.java:1107)\n\tat

Answer (score 0):

1. Необходимо было принудительно указать **http** и **tcp** порты

   - http.port=1028
   - transport.port=1029
2. в портах поменять с **9200-9300** соответственно на **1028-1029**
3. в **network.publish_host** указать внешний айпи (внешний для докера)

> ```
> version: '3'
> services:
>   master:
>     image: hub.rosatom.local/elasticsearch:8.1.1
>     container_name: master
>     environment:
>       - node.name=master
>       - cluster.name=elastic-cluster
>       - network.host=0.0.0.0
>       - network.publish_host=10.126.107.238
>
>       - http.port=1028
>       - transport.port=1029  
>       - discovery.seed_hosts=10.126.107.238:1029, 10.126.107.236:1029, 10.126.107.235:1029
>       - cluster.initial_master_nodes=10.126.107.238
>
>
>       - "node.roles=master, ingest"
>       - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
>       - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
>       - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
>       - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
>       - "xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=false"
>
>     mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
>     ulimits:
>       memlock:
>         soft: -1
>         hard: -1
>     volumes:
>       - master-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
>     ports:
>       - 1028:1028
>       - 1029:1029
>
> volumes:
>   master-data:
>     driver: local
> ```